# Integral inequality with first two moments equal to $1$.

Tags: integration, inequality, continuity

Let $f\in \mathcal{C}^0([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ such that 
$$ \int_0^1 f(x)\text{d}x = \int_0^1 xf(x)\text{d}x=1.$$

Show that $\int_0^1 f(x)^2 \ge 4$. I tried to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality such that $\int_0^1 (1+x)f(x) \text{d}x=2 \le \left(\int_0^1 f^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int_0^1 (1+x)^2\text{d}x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ but it gave me a weaker inequality.

This problem comes from a book of exercises (with a lot of typos...) for students in the first two years of university.

Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: try instead $$1+a = \int_0^1 (a + x) f(x) \le \left(\int_0^1 f^2 \right)^{1/2} \left(\int_0^1 (a+x)^2 \, dx \right)^{1/2}$$
and optimize the bound you get w.r.t. $a$.